# Android ListView scrolling to top

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with custom rows.  When any of these rows is
clicked, the ListView's data is regenerated.  I'd like the list to
scroll back to the top when this happens.

I initially tried using `setSelection(0)` in each row's `OnClickListener`
to achieve this but was unsuccessful (I believe because the `ListView`
loses its scroll position when its data is invalidated - so my call to
setSelection is undone.  I still don't understand how the ListView
decides where to scroll to after invalidation, though).

The only working solution I know of was given by Romain Guy here:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/127ca57414035301

It involves (`View.post`)ing the call to `_listView.setSelection(0)`.  I
found this to perform quite poorly.
The newly generated list shows up with its scroll location unchanged
and there is a considerable delay before it scrolls back to the top.

Is there any better way to achieve this functionality?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 135):

call `listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();` to scroll to top

Comment: that's exactly what I would've called it.

Answer (score 102):

I have tried lot but this one worked for me

```
list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Comment: This is awesome.  I wonder if you can change the scroll speed.

Comment: Can there also be a callback to know when the scoll ends so that I can navigate to next screen ?

Answer (score 42):

I simply use `listview.setSelection(0);`

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you need instant scroll just after `ListView` adapter's data was changed, pay attention that it might not be yet populated. In this case you should `post()` your `setSelection()` or `setSelectionAfterHeaderView()` via `Handler` so it will be called later in the queue.

```
listView.Handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();    
            }
        });
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I recommend you find a different UI pattern. It is possible that users will find your current  "click, and the list changes *in situ*" approach intuitive, but I am skeptical.

You could try subclassing `ListView` and overriding `layoutChildren()` to chain to the superclass, then call `setSelection(0)` in the case where that is needed. If the "considerable delay" is due to just the `post()` call, this should clear it up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give it a shot sometime soon. 
The list is changed in situ because breadcrumbs are shown elsewhere on the screen - the typical android UI designs are a less suited to my specific UI goals and target users.  

Also, thanks for ALL your help - I have read a number of your stackoverflow answers and your CommonsWare literature, and they have significantly helped me in getting started on this platform!

Comment: this is the way to do it, no magical methods, just pure logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

as a workaround, you can create a new adapter containing the new regenerated data, then call ListView.setAdapter. after that call ListView.setSelection(n).

btw, the solution provided by commonsware is worked.

Answer (score 2):

On some different requirement.
If you want to scroll up just like while chatting.

```
        mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getCount());
```

Answer (score 2):

This one worked fine when you want to focus the edittext from listview header

```
listview.setSelectionFromTop(0,0);
```

If you want to select the particular index view from listview then

```
listview.setSelection(index); // o for top
```