# ListView submenu navigation back

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm doing a ListView composed of a menu from a Json Object.
The menu has sub menus, so what I do on my postExcecute() method of the AsyncTask is to clear the ListView and reload the adapter with the sub menu, works fine.
The problem is...there is no way to get back up!!

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889793/android-listview-scrolling-to-top

Comment: it is something like expandablelistview.main ListView with sub Category. IF i am wrong then please give some more details about your project.