# Android - Listview always show the latest added item and scroll up to view others

Tags: android, layout

I am very new to Android and recently I have a project which require a Siri like layout which always show the latest added item only. They can only view other items by scrolling up. Seriously I dont have any idea how to start with it? Can anyone just give me an idea to start?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the item to the top of the dataset used to populate the list view. For example if it is an arrayList called myList

```
myList.add(0, item);
```

and then call

```
notifyDatasetChanged()
```

Comment: What if user scroll up? Will they able to view the other items?

Comment: yeah sure. You have to call notifyDatasetChanged on the adapter used. And the list view should be scrollable as well (by default a list view is scrollable)

Comment: Do you have any tutorial that i can have a look?

Comment: @lmal i tried your solution, it's kinda what i want, but one more thing. How can i hide the old items(can view after scroll) immediately after new item insert?

Comment: @JK9 now we use recycler view instead of list view, in that I would call myRecView.scrollToPosition(0) . but please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889793/android-listview-scrolling-to-top

Comment: if you found my answer any useful please give an up vote to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Add [stackFromBottom](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:stackFromBottom) and [transcriptMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setTranscriptMode%28int%29) in Listview

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

Example in http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2013/07/quick-tips-for-listview-build-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using holder.name.setText(getItem(position));.
Please use this holder.name.setText(getItem((getCount()-position)-1));